# showViewController Not Working

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I am developing an app in SWIFT and I am using the following code to show a view controller on a button click.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
var viewName:NSString = "websiteView"
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(viewName) as WebsiteViewController
self.showViewController(vc, sender: self)
```

it works perfectly when I test it for ios 8 but on ios 7 no matter what I do I get the following error message. I read on a forum that self.showViewController was only available for ios 8 but the compiler doesn't throw an error, does anyone know if I can use it?

```
showViewController:sender:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9552e7cc50
```

2014-11-15 09:25:49.565 Throw[80595:613] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Throw.test showViewController:sender:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9552e7cc50'

Comment: Possible reason is compiler doesn't know which device the code will be run on, you can check function existence at run time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The compiler didn't throw an error because you have the iOS 8.0 (or 8.1) SDK selected. That method is indeed iOS 8.0+ only. You can choose to use it if you call it conditionally, like so:

```
if (self.respondsToSelector(Selector("showViewController"))) {
    self.showViewController(vc, sender: self)
} else {
    //An example of the alternate if you are using navigation controller
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Umm... what would be that something else?  Is there an iOS7 version of the same functionality?

Comment: Depending on your intention and the setup, presentViewController, [self.navigationController pushViewController], et alia.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc as WebsiteViewController, animated: true)
```

which is compatible with iOS 7 and iOS 8

Answer (score 2):

Update - A better and recommended way from swift2 for API version compatibility check

```
if #available(iOS 8, *) {
   self.showViewController(vc, sender: self)
} else {
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Bonus : Use the @available attribute to decorate individual functions or entire classes this will give compile time version check for your own API

```
@available(iOS 8, *)
func compatibalityCheckForiOS8() -> Void { }
```