# How to show UITableViewController programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my application, users can submit a new post similar to Instagram. However, if they decide not to post, they can press "Cancel" button on the `UITabBarButton`, and it will load the latest posts.

I've looked around for solution, however they are mainly `UIViewController`.

[showViewController Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26944432/showviewcontroller-not-working)

However, what I need is to force open a `UITableViewController`. My codes are as follows, which I know it does not work, because it does not conform to the expected `UIViewController`.

```
@IBAction func cancelBtn(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(LatestPostViewController as UITableViewController, animated: true)
}
```

**EDIT:** Added a screenshot for better illustration purposes. So the "Cancel" button is embedded in a Navigation Controller inside `Camera` Tab. I need to open up `Latest Post` tab when users press "Cancel" button on `UINavigationBar`

Apologies, I do not have enough reputation to display image directly.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3LzD.png)

Comment: Where are you calling the above code? From a UIViewController embedded in a UINavigationController? Otherwise self.navigationController will equal nil. You also need to instantiate an instance of LatestPostViewController before trying to push it. Like, let latestPostViewController = LatestPostViewController(); self.navigationController?.pushViewController(latestPostViewController, animated: true)

Comment: Yes, I'm calling from UIViewController embedded in UINavigationController. Upon launching the app, it will load LatestPostViewController in my `Is Initial View Controller`. Is it safe to instantiate again?

Comment: Do you just want to go back to that tab? Or do you want to push something? I submitted an answer of what I thought you wanted, but now I'm thinking you just want to know how to change tabs.

Comment: Yes I just want to change back the tab. I do not want to push.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to make sure your cancel button action is set up correctly. In the action you want to transfer to the appropriate tab:

```
@IBAction func cancelBtn(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
}
```